# Create a database with Apache Derby

Tags: java, derby, javadb

I am using the Apache Derby in a java application. On the first launch, I want to create a database and set username and password.

```
CONNECTION = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/DB;create=true",
                "database", "password");
```

I am not sure that the password is set when the database is created, how can I programmatically set the password after creating the database?

After creating the database, I tried with a wrong password and i was still able to connect and execute queries.

Comment: And so? Where's the question?

Comment: @Andrea It's right there - how can i grammatically set the password after creating the database.

Comment: What is the use case? Why do you want to CREATE a database when launching your program? Such a task is something for a system administrator, not for users of your software.

Comment: @MenoHochschild the database is managed by the application

Comment: Are you asking about authentication? Start here: http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.10/devguide/cdevcsecuree.html

Answer (score 0):

> I am not sure that the password is set when the database is created

If you are not sure, why don't you just try to reconnect with the wrong password and see if it lets you?

Or if you want to be completely sure how it works, just read the source code.

Comment: well, i tried with a wrong password and i was able to connect and execute queries. How do I setup a password?